# Match two quotes not preceded by opening bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex matching all occurrences of two quotes (`''`) not preceded by opening bracket (`(`). I did a negative lookahead for the bracket followed by a quote. But why is this not working:

```
/(?!\()''/g
```

for example with this string

```
(''test''test
```

It should match the second occurrence but not the first one but it matches both.

---

When I use exactly the same solution but with check for new line instead of bracket it works fine:

```
/(?!^)''/g
```

With this string:

```
''test''test
```

It matches as expected only second occurrence.

Tested [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: And what is the final result you need? Just match? Or replace?

Comment: `\b''` ...........

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Replace

Comment: `"(''test''test".replace(/(^|[^('])''(?!')/g, "$1bar")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/uE8eO2/1) won't match consecutive double apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work correctly even in case you need to handle *consecutive double apostrophes*:

```js
var output = "''(''test'''''''test".replace(/(\()?''/g, function($0, $1){
 return $1 ? $0 : 'x';
});
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Here, the `/(\()?''/g` regex searches for all matches with the `(` and without, but inside the replace callback method, we check for the Group 1 match. If Group 1 matched, and is not empty, we use the whole match as the replacement text (`$0` stands for the whole match value) and if it is not (there is no `(` before `''`) we just insert the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad that Javascript doesn't support lookback but there is a workaround.

try:

```
[^\(]('{2,2})
```

See https://regex101.com/r/gT5jR6/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your regex matches not only the quotes but also the leading character. In your example it matches `e''`.

Comment: nop. Just read $1 or group 1. Not whole capture. See what MATCH1 equates in demo link.