# Regex for double quotes inside string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

A follow up to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838311/match-two-quotes-not-preceded-by-opening-bracket). I realize I need to be more specific regarding my regex case to get an answer that works for my case.

I am fighting with this regex already for quite some time (also using the answers from my previous question) and I seem to be unable to build what I need.

I need to replace all occurrences of two recurring single quotes `''` with `\'` inside all strings (so inside strings means between single quotes `'somesStringWithOrWithoutDoubleQuoteOccurrences'`).
It is because in one language (syntax) quotes within the string are escaped with a `'` while the other (javascript) uses `\` for escaping.

Here an example (the actual example can contains multiple strings separated with `,` but `,` can of course also appear withing the strings):

```
'word'''',and''','another'',''word','''test',X,'',FUNCTION('A'' B C D')
"--------------","----------------","------",-,"",FUNCTION("---------")
"    ++++    ++","       ++ ++    ","++    ", ,"",        (" ++      ")
     1 2     3           4  5        6                       7
```

result after `replace` should be:

```
'word\'\',and\'','another\',\'word','\'test',X,'',FUNCTION('A\' B C D')
```

`++` is a required match the opening and closing quote in the string (represented by `"`) in line below the example should never be part of match (these single quotes mark the actual beginning or end of the string in which double quotes can appear).

It seems so simple when I see it, I can point out the double quotes immediately from the string but I am unable to get it properly defined inside my pattern.

---

### Alternative

Another solution could be to replace the opening and closing quote with double quotes and replace the double occurrence of the single quite with a single single quote:

```
'word'''',and''','another'',''word','''test',X,'',FUNCTION('A'' B C D')
"--------------","----------------","------",-,"",FUNCTION("---------")
     ++++    ++ ,        ++ ++     , ++     , ,  ,        (  ++       )
     1 2     3           4  5        6                       7
```

result after `replace` in this case would be:

```
"word'',and'","another','word","'test",X,"",FUNCTION("A' B C D")
```

---

**[Here is a prepared Fiddle to test patterns](https://jsfiddle.net/ozy8syas/)**

For what it helps I came up with not working:

```
/'(('{2})+)*'/g
```

and

```
/'[^']*(('')*)*[^']*'/g
```

and

```
/('(('{2})*)*')[^,$]/g
```

Comment: If you need a tokenizer/parser, regular expressions may be an appropriate *part* of the solution, but don't treat them as if they're a magic bullet.

Comment: @zzzzBov Any suggestions? I am always open for a new view on things.

Comment: Consider a loop where you walk through each character in the string, and add them to an AST. When you reach a `'`, you can check the next character to see if it's a `'`, in which case you add a `'` to the value, and skip an additional index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem: just match these strings and use a replace callback method to replace double apostrophes with single ones:

```
var expression = /'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)'/g;
var replacer = function(m, g1){
    return g1 ? "'" + g1.replace(/''/g, '\'') + "'" : "''";
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57o7bs6e/4/)

The [`'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/eJ7eT1/1) regex only matches the single quoted string literals *capturing* the contents in-between the single quotes.

Pattern matches:

- `'` - leading single quote
- `([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ characters inside the `''`:

  - `[^']*` - 0+ characters other than a single quote
  - `(?:''[^']*)*` - 0+ sequences of:
  - `''` - two consecutive apostrophes
  - `[^']*` - 0+ characters other than a single quote
- `'` - closing single quote

So, when we perform the replacement, we check of Group 1 matches and is not empty. If it is, we just return `''`, and if not, we replace double apostrophes with single ones with the help of the `"'" + g1.replace(/''/g, '\'') + "'"`  inside the replace callback.

Comment: We need to match `''` that are empty values first. Is the string a comma-separated one?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. All strings are comma separated, but commas can be inside of the strings as well as demonstrated inside my example. This `,'',` case is an empty string case that should not match since the quotes are marking begin and end of string.

Comment: Please check the update. I will explain the solution in detail if you confirm it works as expected.

Comment: You are the regex master :D Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I overcomplicated it all. It happens when answering before emptying the bowels :) Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Just updated - the thing is, we know the delimiters (single quotes) and we can capture all in-between, and only replace the double apostrophes inside the capture value. Initially, I was writing a regex with a capture group, but something baffled me, and I chose the "harder way". Fixed.

Comment: Works beautifully. I realized I actually needed to replace with `'\\\''` in the end to make sure I get a backslash + quote, but it works now! I will clean my unneeded comments.